# Build python wheels for different platforms

Tags: python, distutils, python-wheel

I have a library which needs a precompiled extension modlue. Consider following file layout:

```
lib
  |--- win32_py32
  |       |--- _lib.py
  |---- win32_py32
          |--- _lib.py
```

How can I build 2 different `wheel`-packages which only contains the correct binary depending on the platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
lib
 |------ lib.py
 |------ platform_1
 |           |------- _lib.py
 |           
 |------ platform_2
 |           |------- _lib.py
```

and in `lib.py`

```
# this module becomes the _lib module for one platform of either 1 or 2
if platform == 1:
    from .platform_1._lib import * # python 3 import
if platform == 2:
    from .platform_2._lib import *
```